Finding intersection between straight line and spherical line
I'm trying to find the intersection between two functions.

The first function describes the red straight line in the figure:
$$\tan\epsilon_1=\frac{d(z)-d_{01}}{z-z_{01}}$$
The second function describes a tilted spherical surface (this is supposed to be a lens):
$$z=z_{x1}-\frac{y^2}{2R}\cos\theta+\left(\tan\theta+\frac{x_1\cos\theta}{R}\right)y-\frac{x_1^2\cos\theta}{2R}-x_1\tan\theta$$
Equalizing both and resolving for y yields this:
$$y=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-c\frac{2\cos\theta}{R}}}{R^{-1}\cos\theta}$$
with $$b=\frac{x_1\cos\theta}{R}-\frac{1}{\tan\epsilon_1}+\tan\theta$$ and $$c=-\frac{x_1^2\cos\theta}{R}-x_1\tan\theta+\frac{d_{01}}{\tan\epsilon_1}-z_{01}$$
The problem is that ideally the angles $\theta$ and $\epsilon_1$ are 0. However, because of $\tan\epsilon_1$ appearing in denominators, the function diverges which is not supposed to happen. How do I solve this?

If the surface is spherical, why not find the point on the line whose distance from the sphere’s center equals the sphere’s radius?

"ideally the angles $\theta$ and $\epsilon_1$ are $0$" - huh? Those angles are determined by how far the point of intersection is from your reference point on the sphere, and from what the direction the line is approaching the sphere. Saying they should be $0$ indicates that the line happens to intersect the sphere at your reference point, and that the coordinate system happens to have the line as its $x$-axis. Why is this "ideal"? If that is what you want, then what are you needing to calculate?
